# SciPy generalized eigenvalues: eig and eigh yield different results

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Using `scipy`, I want to compute a generalized eigenvalue problem (see [this link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eig.html)).

In my case, `matrix A` is symmetric and real, albeit not positive definite (it doesnt need to be afaik). `Matrix B` is real, symmetric and positive definite. Thus, both `scipy` algorithms `eig` and `eigh` should work and I expected them to yield identical results.

But this was not the case.
To reproduce, consider these trial matrices:

```
A = [[-0.19031723,-0.40125581],[-0.40125581,-0.19031723]]
B = [[1.0,0.38703254],[0.38703254,1.0]]

>>> scipy.linalg.eig(A,B)
# Eigenvalues:
[-0.42650264+0.j,  0.34412688+0.j]
# Eigenvectors:
[[-0.70710678, -0.70710678],[-0.70710678,  0.70710678]]

>>> scipy.linalg.eigh(A,B)
# Eigenvalues:
[-0.42650264,  0.34412688]
# Eigenvectors:
[[-0.60040137,  0.90316332],[-0.60040137, -0.90316332]]
```

This occurs not only on my computer but is reproducible on different machines.

I am confused, why are the eigenvectors in both algorithms not identical? Do I need to be concerned?

---

Code to reproduce (for example at https://www.katacoda.com/courses/python/playground):

```
import scipy.linalg as la
A = [[-0.19031723,-0.40125581],[-0.40125581,-0.19031723]]
B = [[1.0,0.38703254],[0.38703254,1.0]]

print("Result of scipy.linalg.eig(A,B)")
print(la.eig(A,B))
print("------------------")
print("Result of scipy.linalg.eigh(A,B)")
print(la.eigh(A,B))
```

Comment: I've closed this as a dupe of a related "why don't these eigenvectors from different sources agree?" question because my answer would be exactly the same.  There's no guarantee that two separately implemented functions will use the same normalization, and that's what's happened here.

Comment: It's only the eigenvalues that matter and the orientation of the eigenvectors (reflection is also allowed). So you are having same results as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eigh` is only for symmetric matrices and thus uses a faster (and different) algorithm. This is why it produces different results. There are an infinite number of eigenvectors for any given eigenvalue, so I don't think you need to be concerned.

I've never used these methods and am just going off of my linear algebra knowledge and what I found about `eigh` and `eig` online, so please correct me if I'm wrong.